# GraphQL Parallel async queries c# EF Core 3.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, graphql, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to execute a query with 2 (or more) async subqueries. Sadly this is not possible, because `DbContext` can only handle 1 request at the time.

The project is using:

- Entity Framework 3
- Graphql 3.0.0

**Error**

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext.

Type:

```
Field<ListGraphType<A>>()
    .Name("A")
    .Description("query of A")
    .ResolveAsync(async context =>
        await repro.GetAllAAsync(context)
);

Field<ListGraphType<A>>()
            .Name("B")
            .Description("query of B")
            .ResolveAsync(async context =>
                await repro.GetAllBAsync(context)
            );
```

Query:

```
query {
  A {
    id
  }
  B {
    id
  }
}
```

`DbContextPool` do not solve the problem and I do not want to use StructureMap.

Is there a elegant way to use

- multiple dbContext for each subquery
- wait until dbContext is free

Answer (score -1):

I've recently create a project where EF parallel execution is solved.
You can see here implementation

https://github.com/fenomeno83/graphql-dotnet-globalization-demo

In particolar, here a query example that you can find:

```
public class TestGroupQueries : ObjectGraphType
{
    public TestGroupQueries(IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor)
    {
        Name = "testQueries";

        FieldAsync<TestResponseType>(
            "demoQuery",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "input" }),
                resolve: async context =>
                {
                    //extension method that creates scope (IServiceScope) from IServiceProvider
                    using (var scope = _httpContextAccessor.CreateScope())
                    {
                       
                        //call DemoQuery method of TestService; GetService is an extension method that use GetRequiredService from scope serviceprovider
                        return await scope.GetService<ITestService>().DemoQuery(context.GetArgument<int>("input"));
                    }
                });

       
    }
```

You create a new scope inside resolver and use services of this scope